# import large postgresql database

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, import

I have 10GB postgresql database dump. I need to import it into pgAdmin III. I tried '\i c:/sales_history.sql' command but only table is created but table does not have any record.

Comment: [Restoring the Dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dump file. Instead of using '\i' option you can directly restore the database through pg_admin

- Right click on database **New Database** option. Create a new database in which you want to restore the dump.
- On the newly created database Right click and Restore the the backup defining the role name that should be a superuser for the database.
- Try restoring the database

In my case it worked with all the objects in the database along with the data .